# gmail android app like conversations view

Tags: android, listview, gmail, expandablelistview

How do i implement a view similar to gmail apps conversations view? Expandable List? or is there any other known method?

As per what i have found `ExpandableListView` is the closest thing I can use, but how exactly does one change the layout once the item has been clicked on?

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = getGenericView();
        textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        return textView;
    }
```

That is going to set the view once and be done with it...

Answer (score 0):

This view is too specific to be in the framework. The Email app uses a custom [ConversationViewFragment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/+/master/src/com/android/mail/ui/ConversationViewFragment.java)